# Qual maneira para validar o campo input radio?

Tags: javascript

Estou montando um quiz e tentando realizar uma validação simples que ao clicar no botão para avançar para a próxima questão verifica se foi preenchido, se sim ele permite mostrar o próximo, caso o contrario retorna um erro, entretanto no meu teste ele está disparando o alerta de erro mesmo se selecionado.

Segue a forma que estou tentando:

```
submit1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(question_1.checked==true){
        nextQuestion(2);
        growProgressBar('2,22%');
    }else{
        alert("preencha os campos!!");
    }
})
```

Estrutura do formulario:

```
<label><input id="question-1-answer-a" type="radio" value="0"> 0 - Nada a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-b" type="radio" value="1"> 1 - Quase nada a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-c" type="radio" value="2"> 2 - Pouco a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-d" type="radio" value="3"> 3 - Tem a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-e" type="radio" value="4"> 4 - Muito a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-f" type="radio" value="5"> 5 - Tudo a ver comigo<br></label>
<div id="submit1" class="button">Enviar Resposta</div>
```

Segue parte que não estava:

```
var submit1 = document.getElementById('submit1');

var question_1 = document.getElementById('question-1');
```

Forma nova que estou tentando validar:

```
submit1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var validQuest1 = querySelector('input[name="favelang1"]');
    if(validQuest1.checked==true){
        nextQuestion(2);
        growProgressBar('2,22%');
    }else{
        alert("preencha os campos!!");
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<label><input id="question-1-answer-a" type="radio" name="favelang1" value="0"> 0 - Nada a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-b" type="radio" name="favelang1" value="1"> 1 - Quase nada a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-c" type="radio" name="favelang1" value="2"> 2 - Pouco a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-d" type="radio" name="favelang1" value="3"> 3 - Tem a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-e" type="radio" name="favelang1" value="4"> 4 - Muito a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-f" type="radio" name="favelang1" value="5"> 5 - Tudo a ver comigo<br></label>
<div id="submit1" class="button">Enviar Resposta</div>
```

Mas está retornando o erro:

Uncaught ReferenceError: querySelector is not defined
at HTMLDivElement. (scripts.js:467:20)

Comment: posta o código todo para podermos te ajudar melhor, provavelmente você não está conseguindo capturar o `checkbox` por isso fica caindo no `else`. Se existir um erro no `console` seria bom colocar na questão também.

Comment: Adicionei as variáveis que não estavam, no console não apresenta erros

Comment: o problema é justamente na parte onde você tenta pegar os inputs do tipo `checkebox`. Não existe nenhum um `id` com o nome `question-1`, e sim vários ids com o esse prefixo. Sugiro você mudar para o `querySelectorAll`  buscando o prefixo `input[id^="question-"]'` para você retornar todos os inputs e validar se existe algum não preenchido.

Comment: Acho que entendi o que você falou, mas então são 45 perguntas e cada uma contem essas 5 opções, vou tentar a validação via name ao invés do ID?

Comment: Tentei utilizando o name, mas agora está retornando erro no console, vou atulizar o código da forma que estou tentando

Comment: o seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim: https://jsfiddle.net/v4fsxLqp/, aproveita e dá uma olhada na reposta da pergunta onde eu tento explicar o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema está ao tentar selecionar os inputs referentes a questões.

```
var question_1 = document.getElementById('question-1');
```

Não existe nenhum `input` com o nome `question-1`, porém existe vários `inputs` com o **prefixo** `question-1`.

```
<label><input id="question-1-answer-a" type="radio" value="0"> 0 - Nada a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-b" type="radio" value="1"> 1 - Quase nada a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-c" type="radio" value="2"> 2 - Pouco a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-d" type="radio" value="3"> 3 - Tem a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-e" type="radio" value="4"> 4 - Muito a ver comigo<br></label>
<label><input id="question-1-answer-f" type="radio" value="5"> 5 - Tudo a ver comigo<br></label>
```

*Porém pode surgir a seguinte pergunta para validar todos os `inputs` vou precisar  pegar eles **um por um**?*

Não você pode pegar todos os inputs e filtra apenas os que foram checados ou não, por exemplo:

```
var questoes = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='question']");
```

Aqui você consegue buscar todos os inputs com **prefixo** no `id` `question`.
Sendo assim você pode filtra-los usando o operador [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var questoes = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='question']");

// retorna as questões preenchidas
var questoesPreenchidas = Array.from(questoes).filter(x => x.checked == true);
```

No final o seu código ficaria algo como isso:

```
var submit1 = document.getElementById('submit1');

// retorna todos os inputs com o prefixo question
var questoes = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='question']");

submit1.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // retorna apenas as questões preenchidas
  var questoesPreenchidas = Array.from(questoes).filter(x => x.checked == true);

  // valida se existe alguma questão preenchida ou não
  if (questoesPreenchidas.length == 0) {
    alert("preencha os campos!!");
  } else {
    nextQuestion(2);
    growProgressBar('2,22%');
  }
  
});
```

Comment: Modifiquei de ID para o Name e funcionou!!!! Muito Obrigado :D